# Neither if nor else is triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_option').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
        if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
            $('#search_form').setAttribute('action', "http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php");
            $('#search_bar').setAttribute('name', "search");
            alert('Got inside wiki');
        } else {
            $('#search_form').setAttribute('action', "http://www.google.com/search");
            $('#search_bar').setAttribute('name', "q");
            alert('Got inside google');
        }
    });
});
```

Neither of the 'got inside' alerts are triggering, meaning that neither of them are running, correct? I can not seem to figure out why neither parts of the if statement are running, at least one should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.setAttribute()` isn't a valid jQuery method. Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_option').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
        if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "search");
            alert('Got inside wiki');
        } else {
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.google.com/search");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "q");
            alert('Got inside google');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, i saw the previous in a tutorial of sorts. Works great now!

Answer (score 9):

[`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) is a dom element node method use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) thats the jQuery method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_option').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
        if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "search");
            alert('Got inside wiki');
        } else {
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.google.com/search");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "q");
            alert('Got inside google');
        }
    });
});
```

Since `setAttribute` is not a method of the jQuery object an error is produced and the code stops execution therefore it never reaches the alerts.

Comment: The reason why he didnt get the alert is because of this line `  if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
`

Comment: +1 @Raminson. I was going to comment why it happens but Musa just wrote it in the answer.

Comment: @ubercooluk No...[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the value of the selected option

Answer (score 1):

try following to get alerts:
In your case the javascript execution stops after getting into if or else and then throws error before it reaches the alert statement, to check in similar cases you can move alert statement line by line downwards. 
for a better solution check breakpoints with firebug or other devTools

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_option').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
        if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
            alert('Got inside wiki');
            $('#search_form').setAttribute('action', "http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php");
            $('#search_bar').setAttribute('name', "search");

        } else {
            alert('Got inside google');
            $('#search_form').setAttribute('action', "http://www.google.com/search");
            $('#search_bar').setAttribute('name', "q");

        }
    });
});
```

change to jQuery `attr()` instead of `setAttribute` as `$('#something')` is a jQuery object and not DOM node, to fix the error.

final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_option').change(function() {
        alert('changed');
        if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
            alert('Got inside wiki');
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "search");

        } else {
            alert('Got inside google');
            $('#search_form').attr('action', "http://www.google.com/search");
            $('#search_bar').attr('name', "q");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ehh I was just trying to explain the reason why he is not getting alerts along with poiting out the attr problem. Thought he might find it useful in future debugging, just got two downvotes ;) Is there anything else wrong with the answer?

Comment: You told him to change `setAttribute` to `attr` while having `setAttribute` in the code, I guess some people just read the code block and not the note below it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line here

```
if( $('#search_option').val() == "wiki" ) {
```

to

```
if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "wiki") {
```

Comment: Both of your selectors return the same value, was doing some testing to confirm that. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jKS7s/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if($('#search_option option:selected').val()=="wiki"){
```

Comment: You know that putting a semi-colon after this `if` statement would discard it and give a syntax error when reaching the `else` right.

Comment: Thanks @FabrícioMatté ! It was a typo and the code was not tested. Now I have edited my answer.